# <br> tag having no effect on chrome

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I have used `<br>` tags to provide vertical space in html form style. This works fine in Firefox but does not change the spcaing in google chrome. Let me know the mistake please.

**Head section**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

**A part of my form is:**

```
<div id="filter-details"> 
 <form action="" method="post">
 From Date-Time:<br />
 <input type="text" id="startdate" name="startdate" value="">
 <br />
 To Date-Time:<br />
 <input type="text" id="enddate" name="enddate" value="">
 <br />
```

**CSS stylesheet:**

```
br {
    margin-bottom: 5.7px;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the following css code for Google Chrome, set `content:" ";`

```
br{
  display: block;
   margin: 5.7px 0;
  content: " ";
}
```

```css
br{
  display: block;
   margin: 5.7px 0;
  content: " ";
}
```

```html
<div id="filter-details"> 
 <form action="" method="post">
 From Date-Time:<br />
 <input type="text" id="startdate" name="startdate" value="">
 <br />
 To Date-Time:<br />
 <input type="text" id="enddate" name="enddate" value="">
 <br />
```

Answer (score 1):

Line breaks are supposed to be just line breaks. It looks like you a trying to control the line height. The better way to do that is to apply the `line-height` property to the containing element.

```css
#filter-details form {
  line-height: 1.8;
}
```

```html
<div id="filter-details">
  <form action="" method="post">
    From Date-Time:
    <br />
    <input type="text" id="startdate" name="startdate" value="">
    <br />To Date-Time:
    <br />
    <input type="text" id="enddate" name="enddate" value="">
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't count on `br` responding to various styles in the same way in different browsers. The only property you can change with any consistency is `font-size`.

So this is the way to give the `br` extra height.

```css
br {
  font-size:1.4em;
}
```

```html
<div id="filter-details"> 
 <form action="" method="post">
 From Date-Time:<br />
 <input type="text" id="startdate" name="startdate" value="">
 <br />
 To Date-Time:<br />
 <input type="text" id="enddate" name="enddate" value="">
 <br />
```

Comment: Still facing some issues. Though chrome is fixed but firefox is showing the for size quite bigger. I have also tried and use the font-size, diditn help. Also tried to reset the css properties.